# How can I view all attachments that have been sent to me in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)?

Tags: outlook.com, attachment

How can I view all attachments that have been sent to me in the Microsoft Outlook web interface (OWA)? Ideally, I would like to have an option to filter by sender.

I want to view the list of attachments, not the list of emails/threads containing attachments.